# DateFormat parse - not return date in UTC

Tags: java, android, datetime, utc, date-parsing

Here my java code that try to get current date in UTC on Android device:

```
public static Date getCurrentDateUTC() {
    try {
        TimeZone timeZoneUTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        Date localTime = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZoneUTC);
        String dateUTCAsString = dateFormat.format(localTime);
        Debug.d(TAG, "getCurrentDateUTC: dateUTCAsString = " + dateUTCAsString);
        Date dateResult = dateFormat.parse(dateUTCAsString);
        Debug.d(TAG, "getCurrentDateUTC: dateResult = " + dateResult);
        return dateResult;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Debug.e(TAG, "getCurrentDateUTC: ", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
dateUTCAsString = 2017-11-15T12:54:25 +0000
dateResult = Wed Nov 15 14:54:25 EET 2017
```

As you can see the **dateUTCAsString**  IS CORRECT show current date in UTC, but after `parse` the **dateResult**  is not correct. Why?

Comment: Looks correct to me given that EET is UTC+2. What do you expect to see?

Comment: The date must be in UTC. So I expect to see: Wed Nov 15 12:54:25 UTC 2017

Comment: `Date` does not have any specific timezone. `Date#toString()` outputs in your local timezone which is EET.

Comment: As result localTime  and dateResult  are equals. But it's incorrect. They have different of 2 hours between them.

Comment: There isn’t a difference of 2 hours. 12:54:25 +0000 and 14:54:25 EET denote the same time, the first expressed in UTC, the second in Eastern European Time (Standard Time).

Comment: Suppose I have 2 date: my local: 15.11.2017 14:00 GMT+2 and server date in UTC: 15:11.2017 18:00 UTC. What is differents (in hours) between this 2 dates? 4 hours or 6 hours?

Comment: 6 hours for sure.

Comment: Yes, I agree. So as result to get this different of 6 hours I need to do the next: Get my local date in UTC and then get difference between 2 dates in UTC format. So as you can see in my post I can't get my local date in UTC.

Comment: I suspect this is the very common misunderstanding that @laalto already tried to address: The output `Wed Nov 15 14:54:25 EET 2017` does not mean that the `Date` *is* in EET. It’s only its `toString` method that grabs your JVM’s time zone setting and renders your `Date` this way. To fully understand this, I recommend you read [All About java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me for mentioning it, I suspect that there is no problem in your code, there’s only confusion. If you think the old `Date` class is behaving confusingly, allow me to be the first of many to agree with you. The good and sound solution to this problem is you stop using `Date` and start using the modern Java date and time API instead.

Since you are coding for Android, you first step is to get the ThreeTenABP, the library for Android that offers the modern API (if you were using Java 8 or 9, you could skip this step since the modern API wold be built in). The details are described in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Now you can do:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
    String dateUTCAsString = "2017-11-15T12:54:25 +0000";
    Instant dateResult = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateUTCAsString, formatter).toInstant();
    System.out.println(dateResult);
```

On my computer this just printed:

```
2017-11-15T12:54:25Z
```

The `Z` at the end means Zulu time zone or UTC.

As you may know, `System.out.println(dateResult)` implicitly calls the `toString` method of the `dateResult` object. Objects of the class `Instant` produce the above format, always in UTC, as I understood you wanted. The `Instant` class is the natural replacement for the old-fashioned `Date` class for most purposes. Internally the `Instant` holds the number of seconds and nanoseconds since the epoch, which is defined as January 1 1970 at 0:00 midnight UTC. I encourage you to consider this an irrelevant implementation detail. An `Instant` is a point on the time-line.

**What went wrong?**

You asked for a date in UTC. Depending on how you look at it, you can or cannot have this.

- On one hand a `Date` is implemented as the number of seconds and milliseconds since the epoch, so if you use the above definition of the epoch, you may say that it is *always* in UTC.
- On the other hand you shouldn’t worry about implementation details. Conceptually a `Date` (like an `Instant`) is a point on the time-line, and does not and cannot have a time zone or offset; it cannot be in UTC. To make matters more confusing, when you do `"getCurrentDateUTC: dateResult = " + dateResult`, then `dateResult.toString()` is implicitly called. This method grabs your JVM’s time zone setting and converts the date-time to this zone and uses it for the generated string (without modifying the `Date` object). This is why you will see the time in EET on your computer or device no matter which `Date` you try to print.

**`java.time` or JSR-310**

The modern date and time API is know as `java.time` or JSR-310. One good source for learning to use it is [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).