# How to avoid Date transfering to timezone format?

Tags: java, date, jaxb

I have an DateAdapter

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I enter "2009-12-31T23:59:59.999 +0000" when transfer String to Date

But when try to parse from Date to String -> 2010-01-01T02:59:59.999 +0300 (hours changed and time zone too)

So, how to disable time transfering?

Comment: If using java.util.Date there is no way to "disable time zone transfering". Once it is converted to object Date then the time zone information is lost and therefore you can't know what was the time zone in the original String. But if you want to force the dates to be formatted as UTC, all you need to do is to do setTimeZone() on the dateFormat and specify UTC.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateFormat parse - not return date in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307909/dateformat-parse-not-return-date-in-utc)

Comment: Are you sure you get `2009-12-31T23:59:59.999 +0000` with a space before `+0000`? It looks very much like an attempt to give the standard ISO 8601 format, but that format doesn’t have the space. It also looks like an attempt to give “the last moment of the day”, but that’s nonsense. Better to give either only the date without time of day, or give the time at midnight and let the application know that it’s the end of the day *exclusive*.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Always use *java.time* classes, never the terrible legacy classes such as `java.util.Date`. To interoperate, convert.

I suspect you actually intended standard ISO 8601 format such as `2009-12-31T23:59:59.999Z`.

Do not be tripped-up by the anti-feature in `Date::toString` that dynamically applies a time zone to a value that is actually in UTC.

The *java.time* classes are [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by design, using [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So no need for the `synchronized` calls.

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter< String, Date > {

    @Override
    public String marshal( Date v ) throws Exception {      // `Instant` generates standard ISO 8601 strings by default. No need to specify a formatting pattern. 
        return v.toInstant().toString() ;                   // Convert from legacy `Date` to modern `Instant`. 
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal( String v ) throws Exception {    // `Instant` parses standard ISO 8601 strings by default. No need to specify a formatting pattern. 
        return java.util.Date.from( Instant.parse( v ) ) ;  // Convert from modern `Instant` to legacy `Date`. 
    }
}
```

## ISO 8601

Your input string is close to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. I strongly recommend sticking with the standard wherever possible. Omit the SPACE before the offset-from-UTC.

And, best to include the COLON in the offset between the hours and minutes — while optional in the standard, some libraries expect the character.

```
String input = "2009-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00" ;
```

By the way, a common abbreviation of an offset-from-UTC of zero is the letter `Z`, pronounced “Zulu”.

```
String input = "2009-12-31T23:59:59.999Z"  ;
```

## java.time

You are using *terrible* date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those legacy classes were supplanted entirely years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Check to [**see if your libraries have been updated** to work with *java.time*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jaxb%20java.time&t=osx&ia=web). If not, you can convert back-and-forth by calling new methods added to the old classes.

A `java.util.Date` object is a moment, a point on the timeline in UTC. Now replaced by the [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;   // Convert by calling new method added to the old class.
```

To generate a string in the standard format with a `Z`, just call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Parsing a string in standard format is simple with `Instant.parse`. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2009-12-31T23:59:59.999Z" ) ;
```

Convert using another new method added to the old class.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

If you cannot change to using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) text formats, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object to parse and generate strings in alternate formats. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many many times already.

## `Date::toString` lies

Be aware that **`java.util.Date::toString` lies to you**. That method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone. The internal value is in UTC, but this method reports otherwise. While well-intentioned, this anti-feature has caused no end of confusion and misery among Java programmers. In contrast, the *java.time* classes report their values directly without such opinionated injections.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think your system sets time zone as System timezone. For output you might use another `SimpleDateFormat` without timezone i.e

```
private final SimpleDateFormat noTimeZoneDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

you can also use this dateformat for input if you don't need timezone at all

Comment: The first suggestion will still calculate time zone differences and output as local time zone rather than UTC. The second suggestion will produce incorrect data on DST switches.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is absolutely correct (but obviously not what you want). It is exactly the same moment in time as the one you parsed, only represented differently. There are zillions of different strings how to write down a given moment in time, and one of the parameters is the preferred timezone.

You seem to live in a +0300 timezone, and so `SimpleDateFormat` prefers to represent any given `Date` according to this timezone, no matter what the input timezone was.

If you want to retain not only the original moment in time, but also information about the source representation (including the timezone specified), then `Date` can't model that (unless you want to use the long-outdated, deprecated part of its API), and you have to look for a different representation class.

With `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, the properties of the `SimpleDateFormat` decide about the resulting representation, one property being the format string, and another one being the preferred timezone. You set the latter by calling `setTimeZone()` on the `SimpleDateFormat` instance. This way, you can decide which (fixed) timezone gets used while formatting, e.g. that you want all Dates represented according to UTC.